# Are Thunderbolt-connected external SSDs quick enough to run VMs from?

Tags: ssd, virtual-machine

I want to run VM images from an external drive directly and was considering purchasing an external Solid-state drive and connecting it via Thunderbolt to my laptop. I run too many VMs and use snapshotting which is killing my main internal SSD. The speeds are saying 340MB/sec write and 380MB/sec read. Is this quick enough to operate VMs off of directly without causing noticeable lag or other performance issues?

Comment: have you tried running a VM on a Thunderbolt-connected external SSD? is it fast enough for you?

Comment: I've been using USB3 and it's plenty fast. I heard thunderbolt is just as good too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I run a SSD connected via USB3.0 + [UASP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_Attached_SCSI) and the VM runs fine without any issues. So Thunderbold with 340MB/s is also fast enough.